# Restricting page access before submitting other page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have an application that requires 3 step to register. Those steps where separated as pages.

Now my question is, how can I prevent access to `/step/2` if the user doesn't submit the form from `/step/1` properly and same with `/step/3` if the user doesn't submit `/step/2` properly?

I'm still new to laravel.

Comment: Add a session variable, and chceck, what is state of the user.

Comment: You should look at cookies or sessions & then check if they're set in step 2 and 3. if they're not redirect to step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sessions. Upon successful submission of each step, do something like:

```
Session::put('registration_step', 1);
```

Then at the start of the next step, do something like:

```
if(!Session::has('registration_step') || Session::get('registration_step') != 1) {
    return Redirect::to('/step/1');
}
```

You could even flash it using `Session::flash()` and then reflash when necessary.

Comment: With some minor modifications this would work to allow the user to return through the steps. I actually load all the data into a session before entering into a database, and only enter it upon the final step completion.

Comment: Yeah, I need to load all it's data to session first to allow flexibility to user to step back before fully submitted its data to the db. Thanks!

Comment: But I am always redirected to `step 1` even though I added `Session` when the form is submitted

Comment: I fixed my answer, should have been `Session::put()` not `Session::set()`.

Comment: I already change it a while ago since I search it in the laravel docs. but why is it still I am redirected to step 1? Though when I `dd(Session::all());` I can see it's in there.

Comment: Did you copy my code or write it manually? Have you remembered the `!`?

Comment: This code would only go in every step after the first, the first would need to set it, and the second and third would need to check.

Comment: Yes, I just tested it first with steps 1 and 2 to check it if is working. When dd it I got this `["registration_step"]=> int(1)` which should be checked in the if statement